# Segmentation fault in Keras when run on GPU

Tags: python, keras

Here is my Keras model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=256))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Environment: keras 2.1, python 3.6, tensorflow backend. Why does this script fail, with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", when run on GPU? On CPU works without errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you run K.clearsession() with Keras 2 on GPU, you may get a segmentation fault. If you have this in your code, try removing it! Good Luck!

Comment: Try adding an explanation on why `K.clearsession()` would cause a segmentation fault to help future readers understand the root of the problem.